# Element by element exponential of a sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, exponential

I have a large sparse matrix (`dgCMatrix`) in R, and I would like to have the exponential of each element of this matrix. More precisely, I would like to do 1-exp(-x) to each element of the matrix. Unfortunately, when I do this in R, there is a `sparse->dense coercion` which takes a lot of time and memory (see example below).

```
library(Matrix)
i <- sample(20000, 20000); j <- sample(20000, 20000); x <- 7 * (1:20000)
A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)
1 - exp(-A)
```

Is there a way to avoid this coercion in R? As 1-exp(0) is 0, maybe sparsity can be preserved.

Comment: Do you wannt the elements equal  zero to become `exp(0) == 1`?

Comment: In python this is `expm1`, and is applied just to the nonzero elements, the `data` array of the `csr` format,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can try

```
A@x <- 1 - exp(-A@x)
```

such that you update the non-sparse entries only.

---

For very small `A@x`, we can use

```
A@x <- -expm1(-A@x) # thanks for the comment from jblood94
```

or just simply

```
A <- -expm1(-A) # thanks for the comment from Ben Bolker
```

Comment: It might also be good to keep `expm1` in mind in case `A@x` can get very small: `A@x <- -expm1(-A@x)`.

Comment: In fact, `-expm1(-A)` works without any need to mess around with the slots.

Comment: @BenBolker aha, that's magic, cool!

Comment: @BenBolker, in the python version, `np.expm1` can be applied to dense arrays, and the sparse  version just applies it to nonzeros `data` attribute.